# PHP extension is enabled but not working

Tags: php, apache, php-extension, mbstring

I'm working on a Laravel project which is hosted on a remote server. When I run the project I get following error:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php line 160:
> Call to undefined function Illuminate\Support\mb_strimwidth()

So I contacted the server support and they told me the extension is enabled by default in php.ini:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

But I get the same error when I try to run the project so I have run some tests to find out what is happening.

```
$path = php_ini_loaded_file();
    echo 'The loaded file path is :' . $path;

if (extension_loaded('mbstring')) { 
    echo '<h1 style="color:red; font-size:50px;">extension is loaded<h1>';
}else {
    echo '<h1 style="color:red; font-size:50px;">extension is not loaded<h1>';
}
```

Output:

> The loaded file path is :/usr/local/lib/php.ini
>
> extension is not loaded

I have no access to SSH or any CLI interface so it is very hard to debug. I would like to know why this is happening. Help is appreciated.

**Update**

The support announced me that running `phpinfo()` does not return any entry for `mbstring`.

The `php.ini` file is loaded correctly with correct path.

Comment: Then It is not loaded. Check [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: @PedroGámez I did. It does not return any entry for `mbstring`. Can you please tell me where to go from here?

Comment: look at phpinfo to determine WHAT php.ini file was loaded. Might not be the one you edited.

Comment: @RobWood: It is what I edited.

Comment: You can try use [`dl` function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dl.php). `dl( 'mbstring.so')`. Even so, the hostmaster should enable the extension.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Well, you can't reload php.ini without restarting Apache, so....

Comment: @RobWood: The extension is enabled by default. php.ini file is not changed. So I guess the apache restart is not needed.

Comment: Ha. I saw that. And yet, we're still discussing this. OP - get a Google cloud account and spin up your own servers, is the answer. Your host is lying to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try Logging into your hosting Cpanel and from the Cpanel you have a option in it For PHP software version

Click on that & there you will have all the extensions that you can enable and disable.

Try giving this a shot

else use this code to check whether the extension is enabled or not:

```
<?php 
   echo "SW: ", extension_loaded('mb_strimwidth') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
?>
```